# Getting a empty list, but I can insert data

Tags: c#, azure, windows-phone, windows-phone-8

I'm working of the Azure example for Windows Phone 8 but my list returns empty:

```
var items = App.MobileService.GetTable<MyItem>().ToCollectionView();
```

but im perfectly able to insert a row by

```
await App.MobileService.GetTable<MyItem>().InsertAsync(newMyItem);
```

Viewing the table in the web manager I see that I'm populating the list.

Does anyone know?

Answer (score 0):

My guess would be that the call “ToCollectionView” is asynchronous and the value is not yet received when you check it. Try to use “ReadAsync” method instead:

```
var items = await App.MobileService.GetTable<MyItem>().ReadAsync();
```